# What causes a "...memory could not be written error" in windows?

Tags: python, pycharm, multiprocessing, gdal

I'm getting an application error on Windows 10 with python in PyCharm when I run a script after the error my PyCharm terminal looks as though the script is still running but when I open task manager all my python processes are reading 0% CPU usage, the script is utilizing multiprocessing pool set to 14 processors. It will sit like this forever I am guessing and no error will print to the terminal. The script also works entirely on one dataset but throws this error on the other. Although the database is larger the table is about the same size, maybe smaller, and the number of records the script is looking for is about 1000 less than on the dataset it works on.

What does this error mean?
How do I fix it?
Is it linked to multiprocessing? Data size and memory? or something else?

```
Python 3.7.0, PyCharm 2021.1.1 Community Edition Build PC# 211.7142.13 Runtime Version 11.010+9-b1341.41 amd64, GDAL 3.1.4

Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.7.150.1013, time stamp: 0x5b331a30
Faulting module name: gdal301.dll, version: 3.1.4.0, time stamp: 0x5fdf9dd8
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000b7043b
Faulting process id: 0x8160
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8f8795e672f31
Faulting application path: C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdal301.dll
```

Comment: In general, it means you're trying to write to memory pages you don't have write access to -- _probably_ ones you don't have _any_ access to at all. Python being a memory-safe language, this typically means there's a bug in a C library you're using (not at all surprising, `gdal301.dll` being exactly that).

Comment: In general, no, data size isn't ever root cause (if code were correctly written it would recognize and handle allocation errors gracefully, throwing a Python exception instead of just crashing), but code only being tested for cases when it can successfully allocate enough memory to store all the data _can_ be the immediate cause (if someone ignores the fact that a `malloc()` failed and tries to store data in a NULL pointer that failed call returned, f/e).

Comment: ...however -- to fix this properly, you need the source code of your DLL, a copy compiled with debug symbols, and a debugger for C++ (as that's the language gdal is written in). It's not a Python problem, so Python tools aren't what you need to use to fix it. (If you're not a C++ developer, the GDAL people are the right place to go for support on this one).

Comment: Thanks for the responses; I wish I could see where and when it is all going wrong in the process. It seems to be happening when I try and export the results to a geopackage but I am not sure. I will do some more investigating and put something together to send to the GDAL team because I am most certainly not a C++ dev lol.